# gradle exclude dependency jar from parent subprojects

Tags: gradle

For example, i have 10 sub modules in my project, root build.gradle like:

```
subprojects {
    dependencies {
        compile 'a'
        compile 'b'
        compile 'c'
    }
}
```

But module A do not need dependency jar `a`, how can i exclude `a` in A's build.gradle?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it:

```
configurations.compile.exclude.module: 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to exclude `a` from module `A`, then this should suffice

```
subprojects { p ->
    dependencies {
        compile 'b'
        compile 'c'
        if (p != project(':A')) {
            compile 'a'
        }
    }
}
```